# Why doesn't the json() method on the requests module return anything?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, screen-scraping

**When I call the `json()` method on request `response` I get an error.**

- Any suggestions to what could be wrong here?

My code:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/l4styp/serious_what_is_the_the_scariest_thing_that_you/'

rsp = requests.get(url)

sc = rsp.json()

print(sc)
```

Output:

```
File "c:\VS_Code1\scrape.py", line 6, in <module>
     sc = rsp.json()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
  return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 5 (char 5)
```

Comment: Is the body of the response actually JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Your rsp is actually returning `<Response [200]>` which is not a JSON. If you want to read the content of the response, you can simply do:

```
rsp.text
```

What you get from the URL you posted here is HTML, and not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because the page you are fetching does not return Json but HTML source code instead.

To fetch the content of the webpage you need to replace `sc = rsp.json()` with `sc = rsp.text`

If you need this data in Json, you can look into Reddit's API: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if I want to get the JSON from the URL that I've inputted I have to add .json to the end of the URL, this is for some reason (to my knowledge) unique to Reddit and a few other sites that allow it.